# How to manage UITableView background color in IOS 6 and IOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

See this code .

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    [self setUpCell:cell withIndexPath:indexPath];
}
[self updateCell:cell withIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
[[cell  imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[data objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:@"image"]]];

[tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
[tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[tableView setBackgroundColor:_kColorFromHEX(@"#146f50")];
[cell setBackgroundColor:_kColorFromHEX(@"#146f50")];

return cell;
 }
```

Comment: please be clear in what your asking.

Comment: In IOS 7 i m getting the view properly but in ios 6 the color of the cell is not coming properly

Comment: `tableView.backgroundView = nil;
[tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];` write this code their in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method hope it work.

Comment: You are asking for tableView or tableViewCell? Your question says tableView, but it seems that you have an issue with your tableViewCell. Is that correct?

Comment: I am having issue in tableviewcell. Tableview is working properly but not getting tableviewcell color in between the cell

Comment: try for my answer below hope that works

Answer (score 0):

Why setting `UITableView` background colour in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? Normally you would like this piece of code to be executed only once, saying that probably the best place to put this code is in `viewDidLoad` method in your `viewController`.

Here is an example of what it might looks

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
 [tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
 [tableView setBackgroundColor:_kColorFromHEX(@"#146f50")];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change your tableview background color use this

first try this

```
[UITableView setBackgroundView: nil];
```

or this one

```
UIView* bview = [[UIView alloc] init]; 
bview.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[tableView setBackgroundView:bview];
```

To change your tableview cell background color use this delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.188235 blue:0.313725 alpha:1];
}
```

Hope this work for what you have ask